# Python prime number code

Tags: python

I am trying to generate the first "n" prime numbers after 3. Issue is I do not understand where my code is going wrong and would appreciate if someone could help me with the logic.

```
a = 3
b = 2

# n = number of prime numbers to be printed.
n = 1000

for a in range(a, n):   #This i the range of all numbers to be tested
    if a % 2 == 0:      #Only odd numbers are prime(except 2) so eliminate the evens
        print "."
else:
    for b in range(b, a):  #This is to test the odd numbers
        if (a % b == 0):   #I am dividing  a by all numbers smaller than it to test
            print a, "is not prime"
            break
```

Any guidance on helping me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. I read through the older posts on this question but wanted to see where specifically my own logic was flawed.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is really how your code looks, the `else` has the wrong indenting.

Comment: you have bad indentation !` else` must be below the `if`

Comment: I would say to not do `for a in range(a,n):`, using the same variable for the lower bound and the indexer, even though it does do what it should do. Also, you aren't finding the first `n` primes, but instead the primes up to `n`.

Comment: You do realize that `b in range(b, a)` runs on the range `[2,3]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I added the indent below the if but upon running the code it prints periods.

Comment: My logic was as follows:

1) First check if the number is even or odd.
2) If the number is even (a % == 0) then do not print that number. Instead just print a ".".
3) if the number is odd, check all the numbers below it by repeatedly dividing it by b. This leads to the second loop. 
4) When a non-prime number is found, there is no reason to continue looping so break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several issues here.

Your indentation is wrong when it comes to the else.

Also, try to change the variables name you use in your loops to not use the a and b defined at the top of your script and you should see a difference.

It should be :

```
a = 3
b = 2

n = 1000

for ax in range(a, n):   
   if ax % 2 == 0:
       print "."
   else:
       for bx in range(b, ax): 
            if (ax % bx == 0):   
                print ax, "is not prime"
                break
```

Adding another else after the break should also help you in debugging this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will rework the code until i understand the nuances.

Comment: That's why you should have an example with your original code, and this one, and print the values of a and b at each step. Upvote the answer if you think it helps.

Comment: @zigzagdoom you shouldn't need rep to upvote answers on your own question, unless SO changed something.

Comment: I click the upvote button but it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". I am guessing it is a new phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the indentation. I guess this is your code:

```
for a in range(a, n):   #This i the range of all numbers to be tested
    if a % 2 == 0:      #Only odd numbers are prime(except 2) so eliminate the evens
        print "."
    else:
        for b in range(b, a):  #This is to test the odd numbers
            if (a % b == 0):   #I am dividing  a by all numbers smaller than it to test
                print a, "is not prime"
                break
```

This code makes sense to me. You need to fix the first print too.

```
    if a % 2 == 0:      #Only odd numbers are prime(except 2) so eliminate the evens
        print a, "is not prime"
```

Now lets see the logic. If a is even, then it is not prime, you can't start with a=2. Then, if it is odd, check if any number less than can divide it.

There are better algorithm to do this. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the algorithm. I will try and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code:

```
import math
import itertools

def isprime(m):
    return not any((m % d == 0 for d in range(2, int(math.sqrt(m)+1))))

def genprimes(n):
    i = 0
    for m in itertools.count(2):  # 2, 3, 4, ... 
        if i >= n:
            return
        if isprime(m):
            yield m
            i += 1
```

Running

```
list(genprimes(10))
```

generates

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    n = 1000
    primes = []
    nonprime = []

    def prime(nonprime, primes, n):
        nonprime.append(0)
        nonprime.append(1)
        nonprime.append(2)
        primes.append(3)
        for number in range(3, n):
            if (number % 2 == 0):
                nonprime.append(number)
            else:
                counter = 3
                while counter <= number:
                    if (counter != number) and (number % counter == 0):
                        nonprime.append(number)
                        break
                    elif (number % counter == 1) and (counter >= number/2):
                        primes.append(number)
                        break
                    else:
                        counter += 1

        print "primes are : ", primes
        print "nonprimes are : ", nonprime

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        prime(nonprime, primes, n)
```

Obviously not the most efficient. Hopefully it can help somehow.